Screwed up re-activating PC after hardware upgrade - how do I re-activate?
I recent upgraded my PC from my old i7-10700k to a new 9800X3D. New motherboard, new CPU, new RAM. Same hard drives. I did not reinstall Windows.
This meant Windows de-activated.
If I look in the Activation settings, it says "Windows reported that the hardware of your device has changed. Error code 0xC004F211." Clicking "troubleshoot" lets you choose "I changed hardware on this device recently" where it opens a menu to migrate from another computer on your account.
I went through the activation dialogs, but I got a bit confused. I ended up on https://account.microsoft.com/devices?lang=en-US#main-content-landing-react
And just deleted a bunch of my old PCs, and figured I should delete the 10700k and re-add my PC with a new name.
Apparently I should not have done that. Now the migration has nothing to migrate from.
How do I fix this? I bought one license of W11 pro on my account, so I should be able to use it for a max of one machine, right?
I am signing into the PC via my MS account and PIN, not a local account. I bought the W10/W11 key from the MS store, and it shows up in my account's purchase history.
I also attempted getting the key using ShowKeyPlus and putting that into slmgr, but while the command 'succeeded', Windows still shows up as not active. As it turns out, that's just the generic Win11 Pro key: https://winaero.com/windows-11-generic-keys-for-all-editions/

Simple. Call Microsoft.

Windows 10+ automatically activates, provided, it was activated on the same hardware in the past. You can manually activate through Settings. If Windows is not activated there should be a clear way of manually activating and providing a key. Removing the device from your Microsoft Account is easily resolved. It’s not clear what you mean by migration. We don’t have access to the page you linked to by the way. [Edit] your question. If you have the key should be as simple as slmgr /ipk yourproductkey

This isn't the 'same hardware' since the motherboard, CPU and RAM all changed. If I look in the Activation settings, it says "Windows reported that the hardware of your device has changed. Error code 0xC004F211." Clicking "troubleshoot" lets you choose "I changed hardware on this device recently" where it opens a menu to migrate from another computer on your account. I was stupid and deleted the old computer not understanding what to do. So now there's nothing to migrate the license from.

@TylerShellberg - If it’s a retail license key it doesn’t matter since the key is still associated with your Microsoft Account despite removing the device from your account. You made absolutely no mention of an error code in your question. Have you tried the command I suggested?

The command you suggested requires a product key, which I do not know how to get. The order from the store doesn't list it.

You haven’t reinstalled Windows have you? Provided thats true, you should be able to use this application, to get the correct and true key. If that fails you should be able to use the phone activation after you contact Microsoft to have them provide you the license key you purchased

No, I haven't reinstalled Windows. Just attempted using that application to get a key, then put it in slmgr. It says it 'worked' but even after a reboot Windows still reports 'Activation State: Not Active".

@TylerShellberg - You will have to contact Microsoft in that case. The activation state is beyond our ability to resolve. As long as you have the key you could try, removing and adding the key, after the reboot otherwise you also while a pain is go back to the old hardware and get back to an prior activation state. Be sure to incorporate some of this new relevant information into your question

Additional info: It looks like the key from ShowKeyPlus was just the Generic Key: https://winaero.com/windows-11-generic-keys-for-all-editions/

@TylerShellberg - It shouldn’t but since it is, you’ll have to contact Microsoft, to get your actual key.
